# JOLT needed on -Arraymerge

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to use JOLT to merge an array of Tags

here is input and expected output

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "students": [
    {
      "student_name": "Xavier"
    },
    {
      "student_name": "moses"
    },
    {
      "student_name": "joseph"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output as like

```json
{
  "students": {
    "student_name": "Xavier,moses,joseph"
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these successive specs

```json
[
 // create a list to combine all student names nested within "students" object 
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "students": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
 // concatenate all members of the list at once by using "join"
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "students": {
        "*": "=join(',',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]